# Remove member from AD group without using modules

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I work in an environment where in the server i am not allowed to install/use powershell modules (like active directory module).

What i am trying to do is remove members of a group that are stored in an array.

So, let's say that array containing the members to be removed is called toberemoved:

```
$toberemoved = @("COMPUTER1","COMPUTER2","COMPUTER5")
```

and group is called: Global Computer Group:

```
$computergroup = "Global Computer Group"
```

What i tried to do is this:

```
$findgroup=[adsi]"LDAP://$computergroup"
foreach($item in $toberemoved) {
    $findgroup.Remove("LDAP://$item")
}
```

I also tried this:

```
$findgroup=[adsi]"LDAP://$computergroup"

foreach($item in $toberemoved) {
     $base = "CN=$item,DC=Domain,OU=Computers,OU=local"
     $findgroup.Remove("LDAP://$item")
}
```

with no success.

What i get when trying to run this in PowerShell ISE is that i have a server error. Any ideas of what might be going wrong, or other idea to do this without using AD module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use full ADsPath names? Look at this great article written on it. https://www.petri.com/managing-active-directory-groups-adsi-powershell

TLDR?

Here you go:

```
[adsi]$Group = "LDAP://CN=GroupName,OU=OrganizationalUnit,DC=Your,DC=Domain,DC=com"
foreach($User in $toberemoved) { #Again, full ADsPaths
    $Group.Remove($User)
}
```